# I want to uninstall Arduino for a fresh

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I deleted Arduino without Window's control panel.

I make android fire in same name with Arduino forder.
So, Arduino's files are deleted. Now I can'd find uninstall.exe file.

As a image, I can't reinstall Arduino either.
Because uninstall.exe is not in there.

How can I make fresh Arduino?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I want to make sure if the folder `D:\합강테크\arduino` contains the Arduino IDE files or it contains files you've created. I can't understand why uninstall.exe file was deleted even though you've created a file (or a folder) named "arduino". Creating a file or a folder with the same name does not delete contained files.

Anyway, if the uninstall.exe file was really disappeared, try deleting the `D:\합강테크\arduino` folder and setup the Arduino IDE again. If you don't want to delete `D:\합강테크\arduino` folder, rename the folder, say `D:\합강테크\arduino_backup`, and launch the installation file.